# VCS in Android Studio not responding

Tags: android-studio, version-control

I am using bundled VCS to resolve merge conflicts in Android Studio. But whenever I open the any file diff to resolve conflicts, the program stops responding. Any suggestions?

```
Android Studio 4.1.3
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.7199119, built on March 11, 2021
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
macOS 10.16
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1246M
Cores: 4
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true, external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.thoughtworks.gauge, org.intellij.plugins.markdown, com.intellij.marketplace, org.jetbrains.kotlin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Known issue of android studio 4.1 for macOS Big Sur.

Fixed in version 4.2

https://developer.android.com/studio/known-issues#ki-signed-apk-macos